# Mac OS X - programmatically resize windows

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'd like to know how apps like [Divvy](http://www.mizage.com/divvy/), [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/), [SizeUp](http://irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/), etc. resize / move windows belonging to other applications? I know that this might involve private APIs. Or do they all use AppleScript? Are there any resources out there about how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A while back [I wrote about using AppleScript to do just that](http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2008/05/20/resize-your-windows-automatically-for-different-resolutions/). Basically, do the following:

```
tell application "MyApp"
    set the bounds of the first window to {x, y, width, height}
end tell
```

Comment: is this still valid with OSX Catalina? We just need to save that text as /Applications/arrangescreen.app?